# Mechanical or Solid State Switch for 48V DC and 2 Amps current

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

I've been looking for a SPDT switch that can support 48VDC and 2 Amps current but so far I haven't had any luck.  It can be mechanical or solid state it doesn't matter. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't found anything? Any SPDT light switch I can think of would do that job.

Comment: He stated a DC requirement. "*Any*" light switch may not suffice.

Comment: You need to edit your question as shopping questions are not allowed. Try asking for the correct terminology for what you require. Then try searching for DC solid-state relay or DC relay. All the big vendors will have a selection page where you can filter by coil, contact rating, etc.

Comment: all power switching devices are defined and rated by the current, voltage and the interface resistance of the switch which implies heat loss. If not resistive loads l, then must be de-rated due to surge currents (tungsten) and surge voltages or peak starting motor currents.  They exist but matching requirements need these additional specs. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/power-relays-over-2-amps/188?k=&pkeyword=&FV=120000c%2Ca8c0007%2C16040020%2C16040022%2C1f140000%2Cffe000bc&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: DC current, due to cable inductance is also derated compared to AC due to inductive arcs wearing out contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SPDT able to support 48V potential difference and 2A continuous current may be a bit beefy (physically). If you must have a smaller switch for the user to interact with, you can use a small switch to activate an SPDT electromagnetic relay switch that supports 48V, 2A. There are power FET's that can get the job done as well.